# Dividing my desk into two work areas

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, monitor, workspaces, window-manager

What program or system utility can I use to convert my desktop into two work areas using a single monitor?

*Some recommendations for an easy to use application?*

Comment: I looked up "splitting screen" and "splitting desktop", but the description does not show anything else than what is already built in Ubuntu (mostly gridding windows). I might be missing something though. http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000894.htm

Comment: @JacobVlijm I think your recommendation is good, you know some simple application for ubuntu.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes you're missing something: reading between the lines.  :P

Comment: Per Piacere... +1 to your question for the very fast acceptance!  **:-)**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's called workspaces and if you're running plain old vanilla Ubuntu with Unity, go the to gear icon in the top left of your screen:

[image: Gear Icon]

then go to:

- <kbd>System Settings</kbd>
- <kbd>Appearance</kbd>
- the <kbd>Behaviour</kbd> tab
- <kbd>Enable Workspaces</kbd>

and then press the workspace switcher icon:

[image: Workspace switcher]

and be amazed:

[image: Screenshot 4 workspaces]

**Note:** Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>¹ accomplishes the same thing.

¹<sub><kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is aka <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd></sub>

Comment: @Alberto Prego...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby haha, for me so obvious that it doesn't occur to me that's what OP is looking for. +1 for reading.

Comment: FYI, ctrl+alt+<direction> lets you navigate between workspaces, and shift+ctrl+alt+<direction> lets you move your current window to another workspace. Quite handy!

Comment: For example, if you are programming, you could have your working terminals open in one workspace and your references (including headers in other terminals) in another workspace. ctrl+` then lets you switch easily between your work, not getting cluttered by the references, and ctrl+alt+up/down to quickly switch between work and references.

Answer (score 12):

I agree with the posted answers; they're the right answers. But there's another option in stock Ubuntu that runs Unity (e.g. 14.04, but not 16.04+) that satisfies one interpretation of the question, and can generally be handy to know

You can easily resize windows to take up half or a quarter of the screen. You can do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+**any number on the num pad** (in number mode).  This will resize the current window as follows:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> + ...
- <kbd>1</kbd>: top left
- <kbd>2</kbd>: bottom half, full-width
- <kbd>3</kbd>: bottom left
- <kbd>4</kbd>: left half, full-height
- <kbd>5</kbd>: full screen
- <kbd>6</kbd>: right half, full-height
- <kbd>7</kbd>: top left quarter
- <kbd>8</kbd>: top half, full-width
- <kbd>9</kbd>: top right quarter
- <kbd>0</kbd>: minimize window (I've remapped this to make windows take the full vertical screen height, keeping the current width)

So with one window do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, and with the other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>, you'll have the screen split into two halves temporarily.

Comment: +1 I was going to ask "How do you manage to remember all these key combinations?" but now I see.  Thanks.

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10 this doesn't seem to work. However Super + left and Super + right will allow you to split the screen as this answer implies.

Comment: As @Marquee noted, this no longer works by default. Ubuntu now uses Gnome3 instead of Unity, and the keyboard hotkeys are different.  It is possible to switch back to Unity, though, if you're really a fan of these hotkeys (as I was). There may also be a Gnome plugin, though I've not looked for such.

Answer (score 10):

Tilers are excellent choices.

[image]

You can install it the following way:

To install awesome on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install awesome
```

You can read more about the tilers in [this article](https://freedompenguin.com/articles/desktop/exploring-tiling-window-managers/) and on the [AWESOME website](https://awesomewm.org/) itself.

Comment: Alberto, can you expand that answer a bit and include the installation instructions in your answer???

Comment: @Fabby I trust that I have satisfied your suggestion I have expanded my answer a bit more.

Comment: And look what happened: highly upvoted answer!  300 rep already!